# VBA Excel Run code despite userform-window then stop on button click

Tags: excel, vba, show, userform, commandbutton

Found some tips here and in google, but can't implement properly.

Say I have a loop that runs, and I need to show a box with a button "Cancel".
The code must run till I press the button.
In the following example I used **For Loop** and show iteration number in the Label1.Caption

```
' action of UserForm1 on Button Click
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    cancel = True
End Sub

Public cancel as boolean

Sub example ()
    cancel = False
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 1000
        Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:01 AM#)
        UserForm1.Label1.Caption = CStr(i)
        UserForm1.Show vbModeless
        If cancel = True Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i         
End Sub
```

This code runs, but it doesn't react on Button click.
If I do **UserForm1.Show vbModal**, then the code stops and waits till I click the button.
What am I doin wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my code and it works perfectly when the userform is opened with `frmTest.Show false`

```
Dim cancelbool As Boolean

Function loopfunction()

Dim i As Integer

i = 0

Do Until cancelbool
    DoEvents
    Me.lblIteration.Caption = i
    i = i + 1
Loop
End Function

Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()

cancelbool = True
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

loopfunction
End Sub
```

And by the way, the `Application.Wait` makes your app unresponsive

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other way to pause a sub? I check free license on a server once in 10 seconds and I need to wait a little bit between server queries.

Comment: I'm not sure, I would probably use a loop that counts to a very high value (a few million maybe) and use `DoEvents` inside it so the app is still responsive

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark it as answer :)

Comment: You can also use a sub with `Application.OnTime` to do the job.